# ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.* returns phone number

Tags: java, android, android-intent, contactscontract

I'm trying to get email from `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS` and `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA`, `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA1`, all of these do not return email of my contact, which contains an email. I usually get phone number of said contact.

Everything I've tried has failed so far..

any ideas?

EDIT: What I've tried so far..

```
Uri contactData = data.getData();


                    String[] projection =
                            {
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS 

                            };

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactData,projection,null,null,null);
                    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                        String phoneName = cursor.getString(2);

                        Log.d("EMAIL:",phoneName);
                    }
```

For `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS`,I have tried replacing ADDRESS with .DATA1, DATA, _ID, CONTACT_ID, etc.. NONE OF THESE RETURN EMAIL address, however, some return the phone number of the contact, but that's it.

Comment: sure, I will edit my original post and add the code.

Comment: thanks @spaceghost. I will upvote if your question meet the standards

Comment: can yo debug the code and check what are the values you are getting in cursor?

Comment: so you want both phone number and email address to be returned?

Comment: I'm asking legitimately here... does it matter? 

I do want both returned, but would my code have to be drastically different if I wanted just the phone number or just the email?

Comment: have you noticed that both `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` and `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS` point to `DATA1` ?

Comment: so if they both point to the **same** column they cannot be read from one Cursor row, for more info read ContactsContract.Data docs and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whats wrong with your code, can you just execute below code in order to get email address of particular contact.

*Sample Code:*

```
 public String retrieveMailId(Context ctx, Uri contactUri) {
            String email = null, contactId = null;

            Cursor cursorID = ctx.getContentResolver().query(contactUri,
                    new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID }, null, null,
                    null);

            if (cursorID == null) {
                return null;
            }

            if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {

                contactId = cursorID.getString(cursorID
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            }

            cursorID.close();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(contactId)) {
                return null;
            }

            // Using the contact ID now we will get email address.
            Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = "
                            + contactId, null, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int colIdx = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS);
                email = cursor.getString(colIdx);
            }
            cursor.close();

            return email;

        }
```

Comment: Thank you robinhood, I have applied your method perfectly, however, email returns a null. 

Please be aware, my contact that I am picking DOES have an email.

Comment: If your contact doesn't contain email address then it will return null else you will get the email address.

Comment: I know. My contact contains 3 things. 

1)the phone number
2)the phone number (with a +) in front of it.
3)an email address "abc@yahoo.com"

Comment: Hmm.. I picked a different contact with an email. 

The result I got was 

support@unroll.me


Any idea what this is?

Comment: check manually which email address is associate with that contact in contact app, does it same or differ?

Comment: The same thing happens to me, I can't read the email from some contacts but it works for others.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to point out a small flaw when it comes to retrieving the ID of your contact: don't use `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID`, but instead use `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID` in the string-array inside your query. Once you extract the ID use the following line of code:

```
String id = cursor.getString(
    cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Shortly , you need another cursor for the Email:

```
Cursor emails = contentResolver.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
        while (emails.moveToNext()) 
        { 
           String email = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
            break;
        }
        emails.close();
```

Hope it will help someone...